# Convert JSON output to CSV- remove new line characters within values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am calling an API , whose output is like below:

```
    {
        "fId": "GL",
        "totalItems": 1200,
        "totalHits": 1200,
        "fields": [
            "id",
            "refNumber",
            "name",
            "type",
            "parentId",
            "parentName",
            "parentType",
            "description"
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "ref": "#27:270",
                "id": "20",
                "values": [
                    "20",
                    "FID-20",
                    "TS SYSTEM",
                    "TABLE",
                    "1426",
                    "ALIAS",
                    "SCHEMA",
                    "tEST DESCRIPTION"
                ]
            },
            {
                "ref": "#27:269",
                "id": "507",
                "values": [
                    "507",
                    "FID-507",
                    "FCR Ratio",
                    "TABLE",
                    "1426",
                    "CONGR",
                    "SCHEMA",
                    "Test description",
                ]
            }
     ]
]
```

The "fields" contains the header value & "Items" contains the corresponding values.

I was able to flatten the "fields" & "items" keys in JSON , with input from @ErdoğanOnal but I am facing another issue as the "description" within "Items" has multiple newline characters eg."tEST\n D\nESCRIPTION " due to this the output is split into multiple lines.I modified the logic from @ErdoğanOnal as below but still it is getting split into multiple lines for few of the entries.

```
header = r["fields"]
result = ",".join(header) + "\n"
for item in r["items"]:
    for value in item["values"]:
        if "\n" in value:
          value=value.replace("\n", "")
        else:
          value
        result += value + ","
    result = result.rstrip(",") + "\n"
result = result.strip()
print(result)
```

Can someone please help on this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I'm new to python & tried using Pandas library but it is writing to a csv file in single line .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the JSON with newlines:

```
json_out = {
  "fId": "GL",
  "totalItems": 1200,
  "totalHits": 1200,
  "fields": [
    "id",
    "refNumber",
    "name",
    "type",
    "parentId",
    "parentName",
    "parentType",
    "description"
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "ref": "#27:270",
      "id": "20",
      "values": [
        "20",
        "FID-20",
        "TS SYSTEM",
        "TABLE",
        "1426",
        "ALIAS",
        "SCHEMA",
        "tEST DESCRIPTION"
      ]
    },
    {
      "ref": "#27:269",
      "id": "507",
      "values": [
        "507",
        "FID-507",
        "FCR Ratio",
        "TABLE",
        "1426",
        "CONGR",
        "SCHEMA",
        "tEST\n D\nESCRIPTION "
      ]
    }
  ]
}

# Find the header
header = json_out["fields"]
result = ",".join(header) + "\n"
for item in json_out["items"]:
    for value in item["values"]:
        # Get rid of newlines
        result += value.replace("\n", "") + ","
    result = result.rstrip(",") + "\n"
result = result.strip()
print(result)
```

The output is:

```
id,refNumber,name,type,parentId,parentName,parentType,description
20,FID-20,TS SYSTEM,TABLE,1426,ALIAS,SCHEMA,tEST DESCRIPTION
507,FID-507,FCR Ratio,TABLE,1426,CONGR,SCHEMA,tEST DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Thanks @ErdoğanOnal . I was able to convert the output into valid JSON format and get the output but I ran into another issue .The description field is having multiple newline characters in between eg. "Desc\niption" due to that the o/p is getting split to multiple lines . I tried using strip but it is not working . Can you pls help ?

Comment: Sure. Please modify your question and let me check :)

Comment: Please check my new answer and if it is OK with you, please accept my answer :)